# How to auto update readme file with specific data in files?

Tags: github, readme

I'm new to github, and recently I finished an action with auto craw and process data on a daily basis. So, after with the workflow, I can have latest dataset.

My question is, in github readme file, is there a way to show the last date in my dataset.

For example, after my daily workflow finished, the last row of my dataset is '05/09/2022', and I want to see that on my readme file, without manually edit it.

I tried to google it, but haven't found anything, maybe because I don't know how to search the right question?

Was wondering if anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Update:
I found a way to display code in readme file, called permalink, it could show exactly what i want, but i need it changed from code to data

Comment: P.S. I started the question with "hi, all", but i dont know why it got deleted, just want to say im not rude:(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a GitHub action that could help to maintain the README file base on some data files. For example, you can easily maintain a big Markdown-based table from some YAML files.

See also https://github.com/LinuxSuRen/yaml-readme